# How to setup Xcode's SCM for static and dynamic site content?

Tags: git, xcode

I want to use Xcode 4's SCM (GIT) to manage your static and dynamic site content, which I edit and maintain with a variety of tools (CSSEdit, Dreamweaver and Espresso).

I have tried creating repository of my working folders. Repository created, it has "branches" and "remote". It does not has any files of my working folders.

I am on Mac OS Lion.